# Line number in WinMerge

Tags: winmerge

I start to use WinMerge. I would like to see line numbers to easily navigate in files. I cannot find the option.

Does someone know where I can turn it on, or is it possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Menu > View > View Line Numbers

I'm using version 2.14.0.0

Comment: I have this option, but its disabled, any idea why?

Comment: @Rahul I found if you have your cursor in the Diff Pane and then goto the view menu it is disabled, but if you click in the main file pane and then click on view menu it will be enabled.

Comment: I searched for it for 10minutes, and didn't see that.....